# display curreny value in india as Rs.-100 using java

Tags: java, currency

I am trying to display Currency for india using java.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en","IN");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
nf.setCurrency(java.util.Currency.getInstance("INR"));
double val = -500.0;
System.out.println(nf.format(val));
```

It prints -Rs.500. But I want it to print Rs.-500.

Comment: You may want to create your own formatter then, instead of using one that doesn't suit

Comment: You may also want to consider using [BigDecimal instead of double to represent monetary values](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_need_for_bigdecimal)